# How to add derived fields in mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type : Date, 
        default: Date.now 
    }
}):
```

and I want to add a field number_of_days_open field when ever this document is retrieved. I tried using virtual fields

```
OrderSchema
.virtual('number_of_days_open')
.get(function () {
    return moment(this.created).fromNow();
});
```

But when I get order with

```
exports.read = function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.order);
};

exports.orderByID = function(req, res, next, id) {
  Order.findById(id).exec(function(err, order) {
    req.order = order;
    next();
  });
};
```

I dont get the field number_of_days_open. I dont get the field also when I do

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  Order.find().sort('-created').exec(function(err, orders) {
    if (!err) res.json(orders);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [toObject](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) or [toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON)  properties of your schema.

```
OrderSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true }) // console.log() statements would 
                                                // print the virtual fields.


OrderSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });  //virtual fields are visible when 
                                                //the mongodb 
                                                //document is converted into a 
                                                //javascript object 
                                                //internally or explicitly.
```

Comment: Yes, as i commented in my answer, internally mongoose converts the mongodb document to a java script object(order), that you recieve in your callback, using the `toJSON()` function, hence it is required to be a part of the schema. In some cases `toObject()` alone would suffice.